# Unable to "click" Span element in VBA/IE

Tags: excel, vba, dom

I'm trying to automate a web scrape of the following URL: https://www.forebet.com/en/football-predictions-from-yesterday

I have code that pulls all of the data, however there is a More+ "button" which expands the list, and I can't seem to get a handle on how to send the click via VBA, as it's not a button and so I can't send use .Click

The HTML snippet for the section:

```
    <tr id="mrows" style="height:57px;">
    <td colspan="12"><span onclick="ltodrows("1x2","-1")">More [+]</span>
    <div class="loader"></div>
    </td>
    </tr>

I've tried numerous ways of submitting the Click - but one have worked!

Start of my code:

    Sub Button_More_Test()
        Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
        Dim itemEle As Object
        'Dim e As Object

        Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
        objIE.Visible = True


        objIE.Navigate "https://www.forebet.com/en/football-predictions-from-yesterday"

        Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this has been answered but I also see that the total number of games is 586.

Now, don't get me wrong, it's perfectly fine to scrape the data using `IE` and the `HTML document` but I can only imagine what a nightmare it must be in terms of efficiency...

That's why I will post a method to circumvent `IE` and the `More +` button and all that.

More specifically the webpage provides a very convenient way to get the data in `JSON` format via an HTTP request.

To find out how this request should look like, you have to inspect the network traffic when the `More+` button is clicked. You can do that through your browser's developer tools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> if you're using Firefox):

[image]

If you go through the `Headers` and the `Params` of the request you will see how the url, the body and the headers should look like. In this particular case, all the parameters are encoded into the url and the headers are not essential to the success of the request, so all you need is the url.

The response's payload is in `json` format. You can inspect its structure using a tool like [this](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/). Here's how it looks like:

[image]

Basically the `JSON` consists of the 586 games, each one of which consists of 41 parameters with their corresponding values.

**TL;DR**

Here's how the code should look like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub forebet()
'''''''Declarations''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim sht As Worksheet                                        '
Dim req As New WinHttpRequest                               '
Dim jsonResponse As Object, game As Object                  '
Dim key As Variant                                          '
Dim url As String                                           '
Dim headers() As String, results() As String                '
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long  '
Dim rng As Range                                            '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your Worksheet") 'store your worksheet in a variable
url = "https://www.forebet.com/scripts/getrs.php?ln=en&tp=1x2&in=-1"

'''''''''''HTTP request''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
With req                                                        '
    .Open "GET", url, False                                     '
    .send                                                       '
    Set jsonResponse = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)   '
End With                                                        '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

ReDim headers(1 To 1, 1 To jsonResponse(1).Count)
ReDim results(1 To jsonResponse.Count, 1 To jsonResponse(1).Count)

''''''''Write the headers to an array''''''''
i = 1                                       '
For Each key In jsonResponse(1).Keys        '
    headers(1, i) = key                     '
    i = i + 1                               '
Next key                                    '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

''''''''''''Write the data to an array'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
j = 1                                                                       '
For Each game In jsonResponse                                               '
    i = 1                                                                   '
    For Each key In game.Keys                                               '
        If game(key) <> "null" Then                                         '
            results(j, i) = game(key)                                       '
            i = i + 1                                                       '
        Else                                                                '
            results(j, i) = "NULL"                                          '
            i = i + 1                                                       '
        End If                                                              '
    Next key                                                                '
    j = j + 1                                                               '
Next game                                                                   '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

''''''''Write the headers and results arrays to the worksheet in one go''''''''''''''''''''''''''
sht.Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(headers, 2)) = headers                                         '
sht.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results                        '
'sht.Cells.Value = sht.Cells.Value   this line causes an out of memory error on 32 bit office   '                                      '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'''''''''''Prevent numbers form being stored as text''''''''''''
With sht                                                       '
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row             '
    lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column   '
    Set rng = Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))    '
End With                                                       '
Debug.Print rng.Address                                        '
rng.Value = rng.Value                                          '
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

End Sub
```

In fact, as you can see the website offers a lot more data, which could prove to be useful. For demonstration purposes the code above prints all the data in worksheet named `Name of your Worksheet`.

Here's a sample of the output:

[image]

You will need to add the following references to your project (VBE>Tools>References):

```
Microsoft WinHTTP Services version 5.1
Microsoft HTML Objects Library
Microsoft Scripting Runtime
```

You will also need to add this [JSON parser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) to your project. Follow the installation instructions in the link and you should be set to go.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for the suggested approach.  It looks very interesting, and anything to speed up the execution would be useful.  I've added this, and tried to run, but get an Out of Memory error at the line - sht.Cells.Value = sht.Cells.Value   ??

Comment: @MattLee I updated the code to fix the issue. This happened probably because your office installation is 32bit and I was lazy enough to perform some operations to the entirety of the worksheet's cells while they should only be performed to the cells that are actually occupied. As for the execution speed, this should be blazing fast (less than 2 seconds) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through elements of the website like so:

```
For Each ele In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("span")
    If ele.innerText = "More [+]" Then
        ele.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

You'll have to wait until it loads, IE.state won't change but you get body before click, and loop until it changes, for example.